# Incrementing index for list.append()

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of 100 URLs in a list called `recipe_urls` and I am trying to remove the the first 37 characters from each element in that list and store it in a new list called `recipe_names`.  How can I increment the index position in .insert().  Maybe I am thinking about this wrong and there is an easier way to do this?

```
recipe_names = []

for url in recipe_urls:
    recipe_names.insert(x, url[37:0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
recipe_names = [x[37:] for x in recipe_urls]
```

This method of building a list from another iterable or sequence is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Since you always want it to go at the end of `recipe_names`, you can use the index -1, or even just call `append` instead (which doesn't take an index, and always puts the new value at the end of the list). But whenever you have code that creates an empty list, then iterates over something else to append to that new list, you can use a list comprehension instead:

```
recipe_names = [url[37:] for url in recipe_urls]
```